# Dojo: How to get image link inside div?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a small question about dojo:
I have a div:

```html
<div id="image" class="classImage">
   <img src="abc.com/image1.jpg" />
</div>
```

my question is: how can i get the link `abc.com/image1.jpg` inside that div:). 
Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose one of the many ways to access that particular image node:

```js
//Get the first image tag that is a child of the node
//with the "image" id:
var img_node = dojo.query('#image img')[0];
```

And then you can peek at the `src` attribute to get the link

```js
var link = dojo.attr(img_node, 'src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use another syntax which is more efficient

```
var img_node=query("img[src='abc.com/image1.jpg']");
```

by this way you've got all images whose source is abc.com/image1.jpg